# want query to connect 1st table 1st row and 2nd table first two column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to connect query to connect 1st table 1st row and 2nd table first two column
means,

**Table A,**

```
ID     Date        Username  Password              
1    19/2/2016       XYZ       ******               
2    19/2/2016       ABC       ******
```

**Table B,**

```
ID     Date        Username    City                     
1    19/2/2016       XYZ       NYC                       
2    19/2/2016       ABC       LA
```

that when I insert some data in table A's 1st row then i want to check that data is available at table B's ID,DATE

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to enforce referential integrity between this two tables?
In this case you need a foreign key constraint

```
ALTER TABLE table_a
ADD CONSTRAINT reference_table_b_fk
   FOREIGN KEY (id, date)
   REFERENCES table_b (id, date);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just check before performing Insert option try this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TableB WHERE ID=1 AND Date='19/2/2016')

// Your either insert or not query

ELSE 

// Your else logic will be here
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you insert an entry into table1 only if an equivalent entry exists in table2, here's a little script to do that:

```
create table table1 (id number(2), date_t1 date, username varchar2(5), password varchar2(8));
create table table2 (id number(2), date_t1 date, username varchar2(5), city varchar2(8));

insert into table1 values (1, to_date('16.02.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'XYZ', 'ABC123');
insert into table1 values (2, to_date('16.02.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ABC', 'XYZ123');

insert into table2 values (1, to_date('16.02.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'XYZ', 'NYC');
insert into table2 values (2, to_date('16.02.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy'), 'ABC', 'LA');


declare
  n_id number(2);
  d_date date;
  v_username varchar2(5);
  v_password varchar2(8);
  n_check number(1);
begin
  n_check := 0;
  -- fill the variables with data which you want to insert:
  n_id          := 2;
  d_date        := to_date('16.02.2016', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
  v_username    := 'ABC';
  v_password    := 'CCCCC';

  -- check whether an entry exists in table2:
  begin
    select count(1)
    into n_check
    from table2 t2
    where t2.id = n_id
    and trunc(t2.date_t1) = trunc(d_date);
  exception when no_data_found then n_check := 0;
  end;

  -- if an entry exists in table2, then insert into table1:
  if n_check <> 0 then
    insert into table1 (id, date_t1, username, password) 
    values (n_id, d_date, v_username, v_password);
  end if;
end;  
/

select * from table1;
select * from table2;

delete from table1;
delete from table2;
```

Comment: alternatively, you might add a foreign constraint to table1 which references table2 for columns id and date.